# As a miner can i mine my own transaction to speed up the confirmation?

Tags: blockchain, block

So i found here: 
What can I do to make my stuck transaction confirm?
one of the options was:
Ask a miner for help
Some mining pools and miners offer services to allow you to prioritize your transaction in their mempool so that it is chosen sooner for inclusion in a block. One such service is https://pool.viabtc.com/tools/txaccelerator/. Note that ViaBTC does have a limit the accelerator to 100 transactions every hour and requires that it pays a minimum fee rate of 10 satoshis/byte, so their accelerator may not necessarily work. Another such service is https://pushtx.btc.com/#/. Not that BTC.com does require another form of payment in order to "accelerate" your transaction.

Also note that if you attempt a Replace-By-Fee transaction, both the original transaction and the RBF transaction will be considered double spends. Miners will likely not help with any transactions marked as double spends.

So i was curious if i had my own bitcoin mining device node if i could start mining that to push it through like other mines do. I do not care about the reward of mining it just that my confirmation speeds up.

I see these other people doing it so i know there is a way.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can only confirm a transaction if you found a new block, but this is very unlikely to happen when solo mining.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes but very unlikely, when miner solves the block, the miner chooses what transaction to include, by miner means solo mine or owns a pool with a very high share of hashrate